# Azure Mobile Services - logging when seeding the database

Tags: entity-framework, azure-mobile-services

I want to log messages in the code I have in the `Configuration.Seed()` method.

But the log instance is in the `ApiServices` instance and I don't know how to access it from the `Configuration` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ApiServices log property is just a thin wrapper around the Web API trace logger. You can get at it like this as well using the HttpConfiguration instance which you can pass into your database initializer:

```
config.Services.GetTraceWriter().Info("log something", category:"Initialization");
```

Hope this helps,

Henrik

Comment: I somehow missed the fact that it was my code that instantiates the `Configuration` class...